# how to truncate table cell data into three rows using css

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, less, lesscss-resources

The table cell data is truncating only in one line, I need to truncate table cell data into three line.[enter link description here](https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/13706) here I wat to show text like to truncate into third line using css
[image]

Comment: my css is like  <style>
        .text-truncate {
            display: inline-block;
            max-width: 200px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
but it truncate to one line only

Comment: line-clamp() maybe ? https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#propdef--webkit-line-clamp

Comment: that does not wors

Comment: Share your HTML & CSS to reproduce your issue and show your attempts if you really need help. There is no way we can guess what you exactly have. .text-truncate do not tell what tag it it is applied to. Also no idea how is your table built and what other CSS is around your issue.

Comment: please can you check this link  https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/13703